# Laravel Cookies rejected for invalid domain

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, cross-domain

I'm having a problem with cookies, presumably some kind of CORS problem, but I don't know why. When I load my app on my local machine just running a standard `php artisan serve` server, the console shows:

```
Cookie “XSRF-TOKEN” has been rejected for invalid domain.
Cookie “appname_session” has been rejected for invalid domain.
Cookie “1Z1IE4mp5AZjYQ9KlnblgapiAgpRfI3kjQ8RY0JB” has been rejected for invalid domain.
```

In my .env, I have the following:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
SESSION_DOMAIN=http://localhost
```

I've tried various versions of that, with and without port number, quotes etc. Any ideas?

Comment: try domain only localhost, SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost, and also you access application trough localhost ? or 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: @Sebastian I can access the application fine. It seems to work fine. But I am also trying to get Sanctum to work which involves cookies, so I'm trying to eliminate all these cookie issues to narrow down possible problems. Changing to just localhost has made no difference.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your session domain (inside .env) into this:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=false
```

Comment: Can you add a short explanation why this works?

Answer (score 0):

I Try this: changing your session domain (inside .env) into this:
...
SESSION_DOMAIN=false
...
that fixed problem : 419 Page Expired In Laravel Even after adding CSRF token

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).